# How to accumulate TimeOfDay in c# from strings

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I want to accumulate a string array of time values and check if the total time is greater than one day.  In this test case, I start at 12:00 am and add 12 hours.  I then add 12 hours and 5 minutes.  the total time should be 24 hours and 5 minutes.

The problem is that the calculation from 12:00 PM to 12:05 AM is calculating 11 hours and 55 minutes instead of 12 hours and 5 minutes.

How can I accumulate these times correctly for my use case?

```
string[] times = {"12:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:05 AM"};
const string timePattern = "h:mm tt";

double totalMillis = 0;
var prevTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0);

foreach (var time in times)
{
    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(time, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None);
    var currTimeSpan = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
    var millis = Math.Abs((prevTimeSpan - currTimeSpan).TotalMilliseconds);
    prevTimeSpan = currTimeSpan;
    totalMillis += millis;
}

// 24 hours = 86400000
Console.WriteLine("Result is more than 24 hours? {0}", totalMillis >= 86400000 ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Comment: Why do you use a `string` array rather than a `DateTime` array or anything like that?

Comment: The values are coming from an MVC form

Comment: The problem is that the times are not all from the same day apparently (from your description) but your code is assuming that it is. So 12:05AM is 11hours55mins from 12PM. Rather than doing `Maths.Abs` you may want to add a day to the negative value instead which would give you the right value.

Comment: Also what are your actual inputs. It sounds like you are saying that you are adding the 12 hours and then the 12 hours 5 minutes but then your code suggests you have the times of day.

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  You seem to be confusing *time of day* with *elapsed time*.  In other words, "12:00 PM" is *not* the same thing as "12 hours".  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Think of my inputs as different rates we charge at different times of the day.  The form is setting the times and rates.  So in this example we would set a rate between 12:00AM and 12:00PM and another rate for 12:00 PM to 12:05 AM. I want to check that the total times of day doesn't exceed 24 hours otherwise I will have overlapping time.

Comment: Feels like a homework question.  There's just some relatively simple math that needs to happen here.

Comment: This is not homework.  This is something I am working on and, instead of figuring it out on my own, am using this site so the answer is out there for everyone and I can get my work done quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that you are making assumptions about your times.  You are assuming that each time is later than the last time and therefore if it's an earlier time of day that is *must* be in the next day.

Based on that assumption here is how you can calculate the total TimeSpan from the set of times of day:

```
string[] times = { "12:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:05 AM" };
const string timePattern = "h:mm tt";

DateTime[] dates = times.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, timePattern, null)).ToArray();

TimeSpan totalTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();

for (int i = 1; i < dates.Length; i++)
{
    // Assume that each time is at least the same date as the previous time
    dates[i] = dates[i - 1].Date + dates[i].TimeOfDay;

    // If this time is earlier than the previous time then assume it must be on the next day
    if (dates[i - 1].TimeOfDay > dates[i].TimeOfDay)
        dates[i] = dates[i].AddDays(1);

    totalTimeSpan += dates[i] - dates[i - 1];
}

Console.WriteLine("Result is more than 24 hours? {0}", totalTimeSpan.TotalHours > 24);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for.  Thanks!  Just need to check that the string array is greater than one.

Comment: Technically it will work in the case of the array being any size.  It will simply result in a TimeSpan of 0 duration if you have zero or one elements. in the array.

Comment: It also considers calculations such as "12:00 AM to 12:00 AM" as having zero timespan (being the same time).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you're ignoring the fact that `12:05 AM` after `12:00 PM` is next day.

Try this

```
string[] times = { "12:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:05 AM" };
const string timePattern = "h:mm tt";
TimeSpan prev = TimeSpan.Zero;
var spans = times.Select(x =>
{
    var span = DateTime.ParseExact(x, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None).TimeOfDay;
    if (span < prev)
    {
        span = span.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1.0) - prev);
    }
    prev = span;
    return span;
});
var totalMillis = spans.Sum(x => x.TotalMilliseconds);

// 24 hours = 86400000
Console.WriteLine("Result is more than 24 hours? {0}", totalMillis >= 86400000 ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with LINQ:

```
string[] times = { "12:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:05 AM" };
const string timePattern = "h:mm tt";

var timesOfDay = times.Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, timePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay).ToList();
var elapsedTimes = timesOfDay.Zip(timesOfDay.Skip(1), (a, b) => b - a + TimeSpan.FromDays(a > b ? 1 : 0));
TimeSpan totalElapsedTime = elapsedTimes.Aggregate((s, t) => s.Add(t));
```

Comment: This gave me 43500000

Comment: @aelstonjones - Updated.  Thanks for catching that. This new example also illustrates my earlier comment about not confusing elapsed time with time of day.

Comment: I confirmed that this works.  Nice little calculation

Answer (score 0):

It's calculating it correctly if you add a date part.

1/1/2013 12:00 - 1/1/2013 00:05 = 11 hours 55 mins.

I think you are expecting it to be 1/2/2013 00:05   - one day ahead. 12 hours 5 mins.

Comment: So how do you accumulate to roll the day over?

Comment: You need to somehow tell the computer that you are on a new day. Making the string array into a DateTime array would be a solution. Your times should include a date. That way there is no guessing and your TimeSpans would be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this specific use case is:

```
string[] times = {"12:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:00 AM"};
const string timePattern = "h:mm tt";

double totalMillis = 0;
var prevTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0);

foreach (var time in times)
{
    var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(time, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None);
    var currTimeSpan = parsedDate.TimeOfDay;
    var millis = (prevTimeSpan - currTimeSpan).TotalMilliseconds;
    prevTimeSpan = currTimeSpan;
    totalMillis += millis;
}

// 24 hours = 86400000
Console.WriteLine("Result is more than 24 hours? {0}", totalMillis >= 0 ? "No" : "Yes");
```

Notice that instead of checking for totalMillis being greater than a day, I just check to see if it becomes negative.  I still think it would be interesting to convert the string array into a time span that totals without a date involved.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe operate on DateTime:

```
string[] times = { "12:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "12:05 AM" };
         const string timePattern = "h:mm tt";

         var dateTime = new DateTime(2010,1,1,0,0,0,0);
         foreach (var time in times)
         {
            var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(time, timePattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None);
            dateTime = dateTime.AddHours(parsedDate.Hour);
            dateTime = dateTime.AddMinutes(parsedDate.Minute);
         }
         Console.WriteLine(a.ToShortTimeString());
         Console.ReadKey();
```

now the computer know you are on a new day